# Imposible declaration INT variable in my program

Tags: c++, winapi, c++11, int, declaration

I tried to create a little project in C++ . My program should be able to read the currently running processes in Windows and send information about the processes to my private MySQL database every 5 minutes. In this amount of time I can read the processes.

See code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

bool getAllProcesses(void);

int main(void){
    getAllProcesses();
}

bool getAllProcesses(){
    HANDLE WINAPI snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );
    LPPROCESSENTRY32 pe32;

    Process32First(snapshot, pe32);
    while(Process32Next(snapshot, pe32)){
        std::cout << pe32->szExeFile << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "End of list";
    CloseHandle( snapshot );
    return true;
}
```

The code above is working fine.

But if I add the code "int i;i=1;" like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

bool getAllProcesses(void);

int main(void){
    getAllProcesses();
}

bool getAllProcesses(){
    int i;
    i=0;
    HANDLE WINAPI snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );
    LPPROCESSENTRY32 pe32;

    Process32First(snapshot, pe32);
    while(Process32Next(snapshot, pe32)){
        std::cout << pe32->szExeFile << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "End of list";
    CloseHandle( snapshot );
    return true;
}
```

With this change the program will crash, showing the alert "Program stop the work".

I tried to find the problem and I've  determined the following :

If I use the function Process32First() OR Process32Next() I can't declare the same int in all of the program.

What is the problem?

Comment: What platform are you building this with?  What OS version?  Have you run in Windbg?

Comment: I use opensource Code::blocks 13.12 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) and trying this on Windows 10 build 10166

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a lot of issues going on here.  I tried this on VS 2008 Win7.
The "i" declaration has nothing to do with the problem, but may just be moving the stack a bit to hide the real problems.  See my comments in the corrected code below.

```
  bool getAllProcesses(){
        int i;
        i=0;
        HANDLE WINAPI snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );
       /* replace LPPROCESSENTRY32 with PROCESSENTRY32. LP is just a define as
 a pointer to a structure, so you did not actually allocate any memory for the
 return of Process32First() to return the result into.
 So you were probably overwriting stuff in the stack. */

        PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;

       /* need to initialize the structure properly. Memset may be overkill,
         but better to see all zeros than garbage.  dwSize must be
         initialized as per the SDK documentation. */
        memset(&pe32,0,sizeof(pe32) );
        pe32.dwSize = sizeof(pe32);
        BOOL result;

        /* did not check the result from the call if TRUE/FALSE */
        result = Process32First(snapshot, &pe32);

        std::cout << "result ="  << result << "\n";
        while(Process32Next(snapshot, &pe32)){
            std::cout << pe32.szExeFile << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << "End of list";
        CloseHandle( snapshot );
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: `PROCESSENTRY32 pe32 = {sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32)};` is a more concise way of doing the initialization.

Comment: and less intuitive to a beginner.

Comment: Even as a non-beginner, I'd much prefer the code shown in this answer. It's self-documenting in a way that Harry's certainly is not.

Answer (score 3):

The addition of those 2 lines making the program not able to run is just a coincidence. The program should not be running at all, since there are 2 major mistakes:

- *pe32* is an uninitialized pointer
- *dwSize* member of *PROCESSENTRY32* structure is not initialized as described in the [[MS.Docs]: Process32First function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-process32first):

  > The calling application must set the **dwSize** member of [PROCESSENTRY32](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/tlhelp32/ns-tlhelp32-tagprocessentry32) to the size, in bytes, of the structure.

And a third, smaller mistake is that you are ignoring the process data returned by *Process32First*.

In order to make things work correctly, replace the following lines of your code:

```c
LPPROCESSENTRY32 pe32;

Process32First(snapshot, pe32);
while(Process32Next(snapshot, pe32)){
    std::cout << pe32->szExeFile << "\n";
```

, with:

```c
PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

if (Process32First(snapshot, &pe32))
{
    do {
        std::cout << pe32.szExeFile << "\n";
    }
    while (Process32Next(snapshot, &pe32));
}
```

Comment: There is a 3rd mistake in the original code (and yours).  The data returned by `Process32First()` is being ignored.  The code should be using a `do/while` loop so the first set of `pe32` data is processed.

Comment: True, I was so focused on the error itself that i ignored return values.

Comment: Skipping the first set of returned data is not an issue of ignoring return values, it is an issue in the code logic itself.

Comment: Thank you for improving the post. That was not my solution, the flaw that you spotted is visible from comments, I'm just saying, I feel that I'm taking credit for your work :).

Comment: I think I have enough reputation to spare a few points :)  Besides, you spotted the real errors that were crashing the code, I merely spotted an error that was losing data.